# Ansible variable inside when

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I'm working on a playbook, where I get the disk with the name sd*, with no holders and no partitions.

I have this:

```
  - set_fact:
      test: "{{ ansible_facts.devices }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ test }}"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ test }}.{{item}}"
    when: "ansible_facts.devices.{{item}}.holders == [] and ansible_facts.devices.{{item}}.partitions == {} and ansible_facts.devices.{{item}} == {{item}}"
    loop:
    - sdb
    - sdc
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
  conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: ansible_facts.devices.{{item}}.holders == [] and ansible_facts.devices.{{item}}.partitions == {} and ansible_facts.devices.{{item}} == {{item}}
```

How can I use variables inside of a jinja2 template? I also tried this:

```
ansible_facts.devices.item.holders == [] and ansible_facts.devices.item.partitions == {} and ansible_facts.devices.item == item
```

But then I get the error, that item is an undefined variable.

Sincerely VallingSki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display devices with empty holders and partitions only, try this

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ test[item] }}"
  loop: [sdb,sdc]
  when:
    - ansible_facts.devices[item].holders|length == 0
    - ansible_facts.devices[item].partitions|length == 0
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

Notes

- The attribute partitions is also a list, not a dictionary
- I omit the condition `ansible_facts.devices[item] == item` because I do not understand it